# Add additional check in phpbb login process

Tags: php, phpbb3

I've been looking everywhere for this and I can't find. phpbb (3, stock, no mods or anything) checks username and password and if it's correct signs the user in. I need to add an additional check, to check 1 more condition before allowing user to login.

How would I go on about doing this?

Thanks!

PS I know it's a generic question I'd post the code for login here if I could find it >.<

Comment: Maybe read this article for some pointers? https://wiki.phpbb.com/Authentication_plugins

Comment: Mm thanks I found the files still can't handle the checks for username/pass or even make the login page show my html >.>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to alter the html on the login page you need to edit the corresponding template file, located in:

```
styles/{Name of your preferred theme}/template/login_body.html
```

You may need to clear the phpbb cache from inside the administration panel to see your changes in effect.

In order to modify the authentication method, you could alter the `auth_db.php` file (for standard database authentication) or [create your own authentication plugin](https://wiki.phpbb.com/Authentication_plugins). The files you're looking for are located in:

```
includes/auth/auth_{authentication plugin}.php
```

Comment: Thank you =) I am looking to modify auth_db as I like all the standard checks, I just want to add one more. And I did try to mod the html but I didn't clear the cache and I didn't see the changes! Thank you.

I hope I can mod `auth_db.php` to include what I need, it's a simple check really, but the code used is very hard to understand at the moment =)